# How can I use filter results based on createdTime of a resource from the azure resource list api

Tags: azure-api-management

I am using

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list
```

api to get the list of resources under subscription. I need to filter the resources based on createdTime (i.e I need to get the resources created after specified time)

I am using the $expand, $filter as below from the TryIt Option.

```
$expand createdTime

$filter createdTime gt 2020-01-30
```

Below is the url

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resources?api-version=2021-04-01&%24expand=createdTime&%24filter=createdTime%20gt%202020-01-30
```

Below is the error that I am getting.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidFilterInQueryString",
    "message": "Invalid $filter 'createdTime gt 2020-01-30' specified in the query string."
  }
}
```

Can someone please suggest the correct way to query the azure to get the resources created/updates after specified time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, filtering on createdTime is not currently supported.

Filter comparison operators include eq (equals) and ne (not equals) and may be used with the following properties: location, resourceType, name, resourceGroup, identity, identity/principalId, plan, plan/publisher, plan/product, plan/name, plan/version, and plan/promotionCode.